# Pass @objc function as parameter within init to be used as a action for UIControl target

Tags: swift

So I am trying to base in a objc function as a parameter however I get the an error `Use of unresolved identifier 'handler'`

```
typealias Handler = (_ sender: UIControl) -> Void

    class Custom {
       var item = UIControl()

       init(hander: Handler) {
          item.addTarget(item.self, action: #selector(handler(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
       }
    }

    var temp = Custom(hander: myFunc)

    @objc func myFunc(_ sender: UIControl) {
        print("hi")
    }
```

The expected value is that if temp is pressed, then I should see hi in the console. Thank you so much for your help!

P.S.I tried to look at other questions for help, however they did not help at all. I have tried everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter type as Selector and your problem solved. Try following code

```
class Custom {
       var item = UIControl()

       init(handler: Selector) {
        item.addTarget(item.self, action: handler, for: .touchUpInside)
       }
    }

    var temp = Custom(handler: #selector(myFunc(_:)))

    @objc func myFunc(_ sender: UIControl) {
        print("hi")
    }
```